Nuxt proxypass adding unwanted redirect
I have a VUE Nuxt-site with Nitro server hosted on a Rocky Linux running with PM2. The Nitro server is running on port 1344.
I have one site foo.se that has a proxy pass to the root and is working perfectly.
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:1344/

Second site bar.se is set to proxy to a subfolder
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:1344/dekaler
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:1344/dekaler

On first visit it shows the correct site for dekaler. However, it also changes the URL to /dekaler direct without reload so it states bar.se/dekaler. If I reload I am redirected to bar.se/dekaler/dekaler
I have figured out this is Nuxt doing some magic. I am not sure if it has to do with baseUrl perhaps? Can someone point me into right direction.
